# Why string constants are stored in .text section in dlls?

Tags: c++, c, dll, compilation

I am learning decompiling and analyzing a dll file named d3d9.dll, as I know, string constants are stored in .rdata section for dlls, but as shown below (IDA strings window), they are stored in .text section. I do not know why it is. And when they are stored in .rdata and when in .text?

```
.text:4FE45850  00000050    C   Declaration can't map to legacy FVF because a nonzero stream index is used: %d. 

.text:4FE458A0  0000007B    C   Declaration can't map to fixed function FVF because fixed function pipeline does not support generation methods %s or %s. 

.text:4FE45920  000000B9    C   Declaration can't map to fixed function FVF because fixed function requires that generation methods %s, %s or %s can only be used with type %s and usage being one of: %s, %s, %s or %s.

.text:4FE459E0  0000008D    C   Declaration can't map to fixed function FVF because fixed function requires that generation method %s can only be used with usages %s or %s. 

.text:4FE45A70  000000A3    C   Declaration can't map to fixed function FVF because gaps or overlap between vertex elements are not allowed. Offset encountered is: %d, but expected offset is %d.

.text:4FE45B18  0000005E    C   Declaration can't map to fixed function FVF because the type for this element is unsupported.

.text:4FE45B78  00000072    C   Declaration can't map to fixed function FVF because a generation method other than D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT is used.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is a variable placed in \`.rdata\` section and not in \`.text\` section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025929/when-is-a-variable-placed-in-rdata-section-and-not-in-text-section)

Comment: I believe the answer is *Windows*.

Comment: How is that a duplicate?! It specifically talks about things going in `.rdata`, not `.text`, while this question covers the 100% reverse - things that **do** go in `.text` even though the answers linked suggest these strings should be in `rdata`.

Comment: A short string can just be put directly into registers as part of the code. The compiler can put anything anywhere really as long as it works.

Comment: I think these two problems are different, I wonder why and when string constants are stored in .text section not .rdata. Besides, I think if is different between strings and  int variables, I tried the first case with 'const char foo[] = "fdsafdsa";', the string is still in const data section not text section.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common optimization. Section headers take a small bit of space, so it can be beneficial to avoid having an `.rdata`. The `.text` section has all the required attributes  it's read-only and initialized. It also has the additional execute attribute, but that doesn't really hurt. So there's no technical barrier that stops a compiler from putting strings in `.text`, and a small advantage.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely up to the compiler how and where it stores any data. For example, if you take this short program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char text[] = "Hey";
        puts(text);
}
```

Compiled with optimisation, gcc completely removes the string for any section and just stores it as bytes - the assembly produced is:

```
    movl    $7955784, 4(%rsp)
    call    puts@PLT
```

It can see the string doesn't need to be accessed anywhere else, so it's fine to do this kind of optimisation.